# setBitmapImage has no effect - Android and JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm new to Android NDK and I want to learn how to implement imageprocessing using Android and C++. I got some codes from websites and tried to make my own C++ code. I made a function which returns an int array and and I convert this array into bitmap. My problem is why does the setImageBitmap not working.

```
int[]res = imageprocessing(PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, bmpPixels, frameData);

newBitmap.setPixels(res, 0, PreviewSizeWidth, 0, 0, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight);
myCameraPreview.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

Comment: Are you calling `setImageBitmap` on the UI thread?

Comment: sir @Michael, yes.